# Write a file with item field data when item is saved

Tags: events

I want to access all the data of an item when I click **Save** button in Sitecore.

Suppose I have an ITEM A. If I click **Save** button in Sitecore, I would like to store all the data in the fields to a text file on the file system.

How can I achieve that? Thanks for the help.

Comment: `item:saving` event? https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/sitecorejohn_blog/posts/repost-intercepting-item-updates-with-sitecore

Comment: `item:saving` does not make changes to an item by itself. It simply fires an event which you can capture and do what you want with the item that is saving. As I say in my answer below, however, I would recommend using the `item:saved` event instead.

Comment: @DanSinclair Okay thanks. I will try this method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend creating an `item:saved` event handler to take the data and save the information you need.

> Note: the `item:saved` event is different from the `item:saving` event
>   and I believe preferable in this case because the `item:saving` event
>   happens while the editor waits for the save command to complete.

## Create a custom event handler

```
public class WriteFileItemSavedEventHandler
{
  public void OnItemSaved(object sender, EventArgs args)
  {
    // Extract the item from the event Arguments
    Item savedItem = Event.ExtractParameter(args, 0) as Item;

    // If we don't have an item or we're not saving in the master DB, ignore this save
    if (savedItem == null || !"master".Equals(savedItem.Database?.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
      return;

    if (!savedItem .TemplateID.Equals(new ID("{YOUR-TEMPLATE-ID}")))
      return;

    // Get the fields you care about and write out the file here
  }
}
```

## Create a config patch file

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <events>
      <event name="item:saved">
        <handler type="Custom.Events.WriteFileItemSavedEventHandler, Custom" method="OnItemSaved"/>
      </event>
    </events>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```